# Are there some principles to follow on how to create a custom cursor?

Tags: shapes, design-principles, interface-design

I was confused how a cursor might look to not be considered ugly or standard.  I do like how cursors in games look and I am fine with them but when I create a cursor for myself there is something that doesn't fit.  Is there a standard workflow or process to creating elegant cursor that are not standard?

Comment: could you post some examples of what you've made?

Comment: Just give it a point at the top left, beyond that go wild.

Comment: Was a general question, don't want feedback to one or two pictures.

Comment: Please add a screenshot example to help illustrate your question.  I have edited your question and I hope it is what you're trying to ask.

Comment: a cursor is an icon. so the typical design process of creating any icon would apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it contrast with your material, then add an outline that contrasts with that, and a shadow that compliments it. These three things will radically improve whatever it is you create for the purpose of identification and use as a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

A cursor can be anything (clown, wagon wheel, chipmunk, ... whatever)

The reason it's usually a pointer, is that you're generally pointing at things when interacting with your computer. Other than that, I've never seen any 'standards' on cursor design, it's more about aesthetics.

The only other thing would be **visibility** — you don't want to lose it on screen, so you want to keep that in mind. It needs to show-up well on whatever background you might have.

Design it well, and it won't be ugly, or standard. ;)